# PHP strtotime - get next closest "second sunday of the month"

Tags: php

I am trying to get the timestamp of the next "second sunday of the month", **regardless it is in the current month or in the next month**.

The requirements are to use the strtotime function, only once, and without second parameter, nothing more (these constraints come from legacy code).
Basically the PHP code to get that must be only:

```
strtotime('_a_string_here_');
```

And the string must be a generic string. It can't contain something like 'feb 2011'.
Basically I can just drop a static string as first argument of the strtotime function.

I have tried all of these but they don't give me what I want (now the date is Thu 2011-02-24):
`strtotime('second sunday')` // it returns '2011-03-06 00:00:00'
`strtotime('second sunday of the month ')` // 1970-01-01 00:00:00
`strtotime('+0 month second sun')` // it returns '2011-03-06 00:00:00'

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Try "second sunday" relative to "2001-02-01" (second parameter) but be careful if the start day is a sunday

Comment: Sorry, I have added I can't use the second parameter. And anyway in order to get 2011-02-01, I need to call another PHP function (which is against the constraints)

Comment: might change the title to be 'strtotime' instead of 'strtolower'

Comment: @dan Is the DateTime object an option (IE you are on PHP 5?)  This has some handy features for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado If he can't even utilize the second parameter of strtotime, I doubt he can change the function call to something completely different

Comment: @DeaconDesperado. DTest is right. I can just drop a static string as first argument of the strtotime function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Try this one:</strike>

```
strtotime('+2 week Sunday')
```

New Answer:
 I think you're expecting strtotime to be too smart. By not providing a month in the string, or a second parameter, it can only assume 'current time'.

There is no word support for conditionals like 'second sunday of current month if not past, else second sunday of next month'.

IMO adding stuff like that to strtotime would make it too complex to be of any use in normal operations. The correct solution would most likely be to make two calls to strtotime (the first to see if the current month has past, the second only if we need the next month).

I don't know why your constraints exist, but you should probably start figuring out how you can change the constraints.

Comment: That is the same solution as powtac. Unfortunately is not going to work every day. It works only when the day is beyond the 2nd sunday of the month

Comment: added a new answer since current constraints seem impossible

Comment: I agree with your new answer. I will keep the question open some more time...you never know.

Answer (score 3):

None of the suggestions worked for me.

Here's what did though:

```
date('m/d/Y', strtotime('Second Sunday Of March 2015'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// second sun next month
strtotime('+0 month +2 week sun');
```

Comment: The string has to be general, that is without specifying any particular date.

Comment: That doesn't work. Infact if I use "strtotime('+0 month +4 week sun')", that returns the fourth sunday in March, even if the next fourth sunday of the month is still in February

Comment: Today works. But let's pretend today is 7th of March. That will return the 2nd sunday in April. Please, try. I am starting to think it is impossible to solve

Comment: Thats the request, return the second Sunday in the next month from now, so in March it will be the 10th of April.

Comment: Actually I wrote: I am trying to get the timestamp of the next "second sunday of the month", **regardless it is in the current month or in the next month."**

Answer (score 0):

For the discussion about the "next month problem" check http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you just need to normalize to the first of the month in question. So say you want the second Sunday of March for daylight savings.

```
date('m/d/Y',strtotime('03/01/2011 second sunday'));
```

or more generically

```
date('m/d/Y',strtotime('03/01'.date('Y').' second sunday'));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried.

```
strtotime('second sunday of this month');
```